# How can labels be embedded within edges in Cytoscape.js?

Tags: javascript, css, cytoscape.js

We are looking to embed labels within edges in Cytoscape.js, reproducing edges that look [like this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/963849/32416476-a3fb7172-c217-11e7-8b42-50d232aaf0f0.png).

We recently asked this as [a feature request](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/2014) on the GitHub issues page but it seems like it's already possible.

Maxkfranz says that in order to get edge labels inside the edges with a small arrow indicating the direction the only thing that is needed is two items in the style properties for the edges:

`text-background-color: white;
text-rotation: autorotate;`

We tried this and it doesn't seem to work work, so were wondering if something was missing.  Here is [the code we are using](https://paste2.org/XGaswpya).

Lines 83 and 84 show the fix that Maxkfranz suggested being applied, but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick.  It is definitely possible that we are misunderstanding their reply, but I'm not sure where else the particular fix might go.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your text will always overlap the mid arrow.  Mid arrows are intended as replacements to endpoint arrows.  There's not much point to having both.

If stylistically you want to show an arrow beside the text, use a unicode triangle character (e.g. `"\u25B6"`).  Shifting arrows will not be supported, as can be prohibitively expensive for bezier curve edges.